# Yii Active record: How to limit records by condition in related many_many model.

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii

I have got a three models

**Company** (id, name)

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'specializations' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Specialization', 'company_specialization(company_id, spec_id)'),
    );
}
```

**Specialization** (id, alias, name)

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'companies' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Company', 'company_specialization(spec_id, company_id)'),
    );
}
```

**CompanySpecialization** (company_id, spec_id)

I want to find all the Companies that have a certain set of Specializations by specialization alias attributes.

I tried this, but it returns all records without limitations (yii-debug sql query [here](http://pastebin.com/dVy7zHhm)).

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with=array(
        'specializations' => array(
            'select'=>false,
            'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
            'condition'=>'specializations.alias IN ("spec1","spec2","spec3")',
        )
    );
    $model=Company::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

In generally i want to get next sql query in active record way:

```
SELECT c.name AS name
        FROM company c
          INNER JOIN company_specialization cs ON (c.id=cs.company_id)
          INNER JOIN specialization s ON (s.id=cs.spec_id)
        WHERE (s.alias IN ("spec1","spec2","spec3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. You should specify the criteria using `CDbCriteria::addInCondition()`

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with=array(
    'specializations' => array(
        'select'=>false,
        'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
    )
);
$criteria->addInCondition('specializations.alias', array("spec1","spec2","spec3"));;
$model=Company::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just add

```
$criteria->together=true;
```